# Excel VBA to subtract value if have same label

Tags: vba, excel

I'm going to do something about subtract value of time if the cell have same packet label, suppose i have data like :

```
| 1  |   A   |  01  |   x   |                  
| 2  |   B   |  03  |   x   |                  
| 3  |   A   |  05  |   x   |                 
| 4  |   C   |  06  |   x   |            
| 5  |   B   |  09  |   x   |  
| 6  |   A   |  11  |   x   |
```

and the value should be something like this :

```
| 1  |   A   |  01  |   4   | >> Value of subtract time A1 from A3 5-1 = 4  
| 2  |   B   |  03  |   6   | >> Value of subtract time B2 from A5 9-3 = 6   
| 3  |   A   |  05  |   6   | >> Value of subtract time A3 from A6 11-5 = 6 
| 4  |   C   |  06  | value |  
| 5  |   B   |  09  | value |   
| 6  |   A   |  11  | value |
```

My current code is :

```
sub deltaip()

dim x as long
dim i as long

for i = 2 to rows.count
for x = 3 to rows.count

if cells(i,2).value = cells(x,2).value then cells(i,4) = cells(x,3).value-cells(i,3).value

next x
next i

End Sub
```

But it's stuck, I need to make the X loop  to stop everytime it found same value, do the subtraction and proceed to next x. Also i found that on the next I loop, the X won't reset from 3, but contine from last X value, what's wrong?

could someone help me? I'm pretty new to VBA on Excel, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by changing into Do While like this code (Code on actual sheet) :

```
Sub deltaip()

Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = 3
x = 3

For i = 2 To 11

Do Until Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(x, 3).Value
x = x + 1
If x > 12 Then Exit Do
Loop

If Cells(x, 2).Value - Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then
Cells(i, 8) = Cells(x, 2).Value - Cells(i, 2).Value
Else
Cells(i, 8) = ""
End If

n = n + 1
x = n



Next i

End Sub
```